# Call to a member function first() on null after Payment successful on my laravel website

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, checkout

> Call to a member function first() on null
> 54
> Error
> …/platform/plugins/stripe/src/Http/Controllers/StripeController.php38

This is the code of my stripe controller: the payment is successful but after that it shows this error instead of confirming the payment:

```php
class StripeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param StripePaymentCallbackRequest $request
     * @param StripePaymentService $stripePaymentService
     * @param BaseHttpResponse $response
     * @return BaseHttpResponse
     */
    public function success(StripePaymentCallbackRequest $request, StripePaymentService $stripePaymentService, BaseHttpResponse $response)
    {
        try {
            $stripePaymentService->setClient();

            $session = Session::retrieve($request->input('session_id'));

            if ($session->payment_status == 'paid') {
                $metadata = $session->metadata->toArray();

                $orderIds = json_decode($metadata['order_id'], true);

                $charge = PaymentIntent::retrieve($session->payment_intent);

                $chargeId = $charge->charges->first()->id;

                do_action(PAYMENT_ACTION_PAYMENT_PROCESSED, [
                    'amount' => $metadata['amount'],
                    'currency' => strtoupper($session->currency),
                    'charge_id' => $chargeId,
                    'order_id' => $orderIds,
                    'customer_id' => Arr::get($metadata, 'customer_id'),
                    'customer_type' => Arr::get($metadata, 'customer_type'),
                    'payment_channel' => STRIPE_PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME,
                    'status' => PaymentStatusEnum::COMPLETED,
                ]);

                return $response
                    ->setNextUrl(PaymentHelper::getRedirectURL() . '?charge_id=' . $chargeId)
                    ->setMessage(__('Checkout successfully!'));
            }

            return $response
                ->setError()
                ->setNextUrl(PaymentHelper::getCancelURL())
                ->setMessage(__('Payment failed!'));
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return $response
                ->setError()
                ->setNextUrl(PaymentHelper::getCancelURL())
                ->withInput()
                ->setMessage($exception->getMessage() ?: __('Payment failed!'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param BaseHttpResponse $response
     * @return BaseHttpResponse
     */
    public function error(BaseHttpResponse $response)
    {
        return $response
            ->setError()
            ->setNextUrl(PaymentHelper::getCancelURL())
            ->withInput()
            ->setMessage(__('Payment failed!'));
    }
}
```

I've tried all the solutions from StackOverflow but none of them worked, please help me out with this.

Comment: And which line is the one giving you the error... Looks like it is here: `$chargeId = $charge->charges->first()->id;` as it is the only `first()` I can find. The error is self-explanatory, you are trying to call `first` on `$charge->charges`, but `charges` (the property not the variable) is `null`... What is `PaymentIntent`? Is it from Stripe?

Answer (score 2):

```
$charge = PaymentIntent::retrieve($session->payment_intent);
$chargeId = $charge->charges->first()->id;
```

If I understand this code correctly, you're looking for the `id` of the first element of the Payment Intent's `charges` array.
The `first()` function likely returns an error because there is no `charges` array.

Depending on the API version set on your Account / requests, you may not have a `charges` array on your Payment Intents - it was replaced by the `latest_charge` attribute as of '2022-11-15':
https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-11-15

If I'm correct, your code should run correctly if you hardset your API version to something older like '2022-08-01':
https://stripe.com/docs/libraries/set-version

That said, I would suggest changing your code to work with the new changes:

```
$charge = PaymentIntent::retrieve(
   $session->payment_intent,
   ['expand' => ['latest_charge']]
);
$chargeId = $charge->latest_charge->id;
```

(You'll need to `expand` the `latest_charge` to get it returned)

FYI, I'm not sure if the code above will work, as you seem to be using the old formatting of stripe-php, which dates back to pre-7.33.0 releases, these are considered legacy. Find out more here:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/wiki/Migration-to-StripeClient-and-services-in-7.33.0